# why "map parameters and static map" warning occours and what are its effects?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am setting up a navigation as explained in [Navigation Stack Setup Tutorial stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) for P3AT spawned. after making all the costmap files **when i run the move_base.launch file the following warning appears:-**

```
[WARN] [1413713361.087470432]: You have set map parameters, but also requested to use the static map.  Your parameters will be overwritten by those given by the map server
```

**I just want to know why this error occurs and what are its effects on automated navigation??**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195304/why-%22map-parameters-and-static-map%22-warning-occours-and-what-are-its-effects??/) by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2014-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably specified something like a fixed width and height for the costmap. The message tells you that these parameters will be ignored, because width/height/resolution will be set from the static map.

Navigation with a static map will work fine. The warning mainly tells you to check that your setup is what you want.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-10-21**:
thanks @dornhege, i have tried your suggestion but i am still getting this warning. [A complete Question is fired here](http://answers.ros.org/question/195523/warning-map-update-loop-missed-its-desired-rate-keeps-on-comming/), please help me to solve this.